# How to emit a CustoomEvent from a Typescript module?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, custom-events

How do I emit `CustomEvents` from a compiled Typescript module?

I have a module whose constructor takes an HTML element ID as input.  It does stuff with the HTML element and at some point tries to create and dispatch a `CustomEvent` to the HTML element.  Something like:

```
export class MyControls {
    //
    // Events
    public eventStarted = new CustomEvent(
        'MyControls.EventStarted'
    )
    
    startButtonId: string
    
    constructor(startButtonId: string) {
        this.startButtonId = startButtonId
    }
    
    someMethod() {
        document.getElementById(
            this.startButtonId
        ).dispatchEvent(
            this.eventStarted
        )
    }
    
}
```

In the javascript file:

```
$('button#myButton).on('MyControls.EventStarted', function(){
    console.log('Something happened');
});

let controls = new MyControls('myButton');
```

The `console.log()` in the javascript code never happens.  The HTML element exists before I instantiate `MyControls`.  I am missing something and I am not sure what I am looking for.

Ideas?

Comment: if that's a copy paste: look at the syntax highlighting, and then notice you are missing a `'` after `button#myButton`. Then wonder about why your ide/code editor didn't make that as obvious as it did here =)

Comment: jQuery custom events and DOM custom events are not the same unfortunately. Use `addEventListener('MyControls.EventStarted', …)` if you want to use DOM event, use `$('#'+this.startButtonId).trigger('MyControls.EventStarted')` if you want to use jQuery.